# Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv2d_1/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,10000,80], [3,3,80,16]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras version 2.3.1 and TensorFlow 2.0.0.

I induce the titular error on my instantiation of the first convolutional layer in my network:

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, input_shape=(1, 10000, 80)),
    LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=3),
    Conv2D(16, 3),
    LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=3),
    Conv2D(16, 3),
    LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=3),
    Conv2D(16, 3),
    LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=3),
    Dense(256),
    LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01),
    Dense(32),
    LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')])
```

As I am aware, the TF dimensional ordering should be set as (samples, rows, columns). My input is an array of shape 1000, 80.

I have tried all of the fixes I have found online, including:

```
K.common.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
K.set_image_data_format('channels_last')
K.tensorflow_backend.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
```

However, all of these either do not change anything (as in the case of the first two) or fail at those lines (the latter two).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of these fixes will work if the `input_shape` is wrong. The `input_shape` for a `Conv2D` layers should be `(width, height, channels)`, the samples dimension is not included as its implictly inserted by Keras.

The `input_shape` you gave would be interpreted with width of one, which is a problem. You need to format your `input_shape` correctly and also add the channels dimension.

Comment: I see on Keras documentation ([https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/]) that `Conv2D` layers `(batch, rows, cols, channels)` when data format is `channels_last`. I figured that with with input of shape `1000, 80`, I would need `input_size=(1000, 80, 1)`. For 1000 rows, 80 columns, and a single channel. Can you explain how I am misinterpreting this and/or what the correct input size would be given this?

Comment: @BrownPhilip As I said, the samples dimension is not part of the input_shape, so it should be just (100, 80, 1), assuming its a one channel image.